# Russian text in Bookmarks/Saves view

Tags: bug, saves

I'm in the USA, don't speak Russian and haven't visited the Russian version of SO, if that makes any difference.

I just went to bookmark a page, and the dialog that pops up and normally says "Saved to "For Later"" said `На потом`. Clicking on my profile and choosing Saves shows the following:

[image: Saves in Russian]

You can see the Russian text for `На потом` (translates to `For Later`), and `Все закладки` (`All Bookmarks`).

It occurs in multiple web browsers. I haven't changed any language settings (or any settings for that matter) recently.

I assume this is a bug of some sort?

Comment: works for me...

Comment: No repro. I don't even see the three translated on ru.SO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqE1U.png

Comment: I think I remember a bug like this coming up before, and it was to do with some cache not being cleared.

Comment: MSE: [Why are the saves categories in wrong language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384616/why-are-the-saves-categories-in-wrong-language)

Comment: *I assume this is a bug of some sort?* Nyet, is just cache, no to worry.

Comment: [I'm able to reproduce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP34r.png). I'm from Switzerland; I've only ever browsed Stack Overflow in English.

Comment: Our cache is strong, like bear. You no worry, it's nice though.

Comment: I'm seeing this today as well.

Comment: Happened again in 02.2023: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyLZo.png

Comment: Verbatim issue for me today after having not been on the site much lately.